# How to add shadow of margin of error to a diagramm

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, reshape, survival

I try to create a survival prediction' diagramm

```
library("survival")
# fit regression
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + wt.loss, data =  lung)
res.cox
```

Fit a new data

```
sex_df <- with(lung,
               data.frame(sex = c(1, 2), 
                          age = rep(mean(age, na.rm = TRUE), 2),
                          wt.loss = rep(mean(wt.loss, na.rm = TRUE), 2)  ))
```

The diagramm

```
library("ggplot2")
fit <- survfit(res.cox, newdata = sex_df)
library(reshape2)
dat = data.frame(surv = fit$surv,lower= fit$lower, upper = fit$upper,time= fit$time)
head(dat)
head(melt(dat, id="time"))
data = melt(dat, id="time")

obj = strsplit(as.character(data$variable), "[.]") # делим текст на объекты по запятой

data$line = sapply(obj, '[', 1)
data$number = sapply(obj, '[', 2)

ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=value, group=variable)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=line, color=as.factor(number), size=line)) +
  # geom_point(aes(color=number)) +
  theme(legend.position="top", axis.text = element_text(size = 20), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=40),
        legend.key.size = unit(3,"line"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c( 2,1,2))+ # "dotted", "twodash","dotted"
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF", 'red'))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(2, 3.5, 2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 840),
                     breaks=seq(0, 840, 120)) + ylab("Surv prob") + 
  guides(linetype = FALSE, size = FALSE, color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5))) + labs(color='') + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = rep(data$value[data$line == 'lower' & 
                                          data$number == "1"],6), 
       ymax = rep(data$value[data$line == 'upper' & data$number == "1"],6)), 
       fill = "#E7B800",alpha=0.1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = rep(data$value[data$line == 'lower' & data$number == "2"],6), 
                  ymax = rep(data$value[data$line == 'upper' & data$number == "2"],6)), 
              fill = "#2E9FDF",alpha=0.1)
```

[image]

**The QUESTION**
The diagramm is ok but but I have to add with hands this

```
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = rep(data$value[data$line == 'lower' & data$number == "2"],6), 
                      ymax = rep(data$value[data$line == 'upper' & data$number == "2"],6)), 
                  fill = "#2E9FDF",alpha=0.1)
```

And if there were three, but not two elements in the new data, you would have to rewrite the code. Is it possible to rewrite the code so that it does not depend on the number of elements of new data?
I try to use a loop

```
temp = list()
uniq <- unique(unlist(data$number))
for (i in 1:length(levels(as.factor(data$number)))) {
  n = geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = rep(data$value[data$line == 'lower' & data$number == uniq[i]],6), 
                        ymax = rep(data$value[data$line == 'upper' & data$number == uniq[i]],6)), 
                  fill = "#2E9FDF", alpha=0.1) # 
  temp = append(n, temp)
  }
temp
```

but this is an unsuccessful attempt. Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reshaping the data.frame so that `surv`, `lower`, and `upper` are separate vectors, you can group the `geom_ribbon` by your elements rather than the "meaning" of the lines.

Below is the code using the `tidyr` package; the first section is simply your code for generating the data.

```
library(survival)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# fit regression
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + wt.loss, data =  lung)
res.cox

sex_df <- with(lung,
               data.frame(sex = c(1, 2), 
                          age = rep(mean(age, na.rm = TRUE), 2),
                          wt.loss = rep(mean(wt.loss, na.rm = TRUE), 2)  ))


fit <- survfit(res.cox, newdata = sex_df)

dat = data.frame(surv = fit$surv,lower= fit$lower, upper = fit$upper,time= fit$time)

head(dat)
head(melt(dat, id="time"))
data = melt(dat, id="time")

# Reformats the data into format with the survival curve and the confidence intervals in their own columns
library(tidyr)

data_wide <- data %>%
  separate(col = variable, into = c("type", "sex"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  spread(key = type, value = value)


ggplot(data = data_wide) +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = surv, group = sex, colour = sex),
            size = 3.5,
            linetype = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = lower, group = sex, colour = sex),
            size = 2,
            linetype = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = upper, group = sex, colour = sex),
            size = 2,
            linetype = 2) +
  # Geom_ribbom now grouped by sex
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = time, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, group = sex, fill = sex),
              alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF")) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 840),
                     breaks = seq(0, 840, 120)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        axis.text = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 40),
        legend.key.size = unit(3, "line")) +
  ylab("Surv prob")
```

And this is the plot output: 
[image]

We add another element to test if this works, you will have to add more colours to `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_fill_manual`.

```
library(dplyr)
data_wide2 <- filter(data_wide, sex == "1") %>%
  mutate(sex = "3",
         surv = surv - 0.2,
         upper = upper - 0.2,
         lower = lower - 0.2) %>%
  rbind(data_wide)
```

This gives the following plot:

[image]